# Which mesh processing library for python to chose

Tags: library, python, data-visualization, image-processing, 3d

for a project I'm writing I need a library for python to process ".off" files (3d models mesh files),
 so I would be able to visualize them and save an image of several views of the model . 
(the visualization is for that purpose, I just didn't find a lib with such option)

I found the following libraries, and they seem fine but I'm not sure what to chose:

- [PyMesh](https://pymesh.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)
- [OpenMesh](https://www.openmesh.org/media/Documentations/OpenMesh-6.1-Documentation/index.html)
- [TriMesh](https://github.com/mikedh/trimesh)
- [Open3d](http://www.open3d.org/docs/release/)

Can you recommend on another library or which of the ones here is preferred?

Answer (score 0):

Can't comment on those, sorry.
[Meshio](https://github.com/nschloe/meshio) reads / writes many different formats;
an example --

```
""" meshio loopback test """
import numpy as np
import meshio  # https://github.com/nschloe/meshio
import meshzoo  # https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo

def pr( txt, x ):
    print( "%s: %s \n%s .T" % (
            txt, x.shape, x.T ))

np.set_printoptions( threshold=20, edgeitems=10, linewidth=120,
        formatter = dict( float = lambda x: "%.2g" % x ))  # float arrays %.2g
print( 80 * "▄" )

#...............................................................................
points, cells = meshzoo.tube( n=10 )
pr( "points", points )
pr( "cells", cells )

cellsdict = {"triangle": cells}  # line triangle tetra
mesh = meshio.Mesh( points, cellsdict )

    # loopback test, write read --
mesh.write( "tmp-tube.off" )

print( "\nmeshio.read should be the same --" )  # reordered ?
meshin = meshio.read( "tmp-tube.off" )
points = meshin.points
pr( "points", points )
for typ, data in meshin.cells_dict.items():
    pr( typ, data )
```